# Returning records from database between two dates

Tags: java, sql

I've created a program using Java that connects to a database and allows the user to submit a record. This record includes a unique reference number and started date (Variable: StartedDate).

I want to enable the user to search for the amount of cases submitted between two dates (the first day of the month and todays date).

So far I have the SQL query

```
select * from cases where StartDate>'***' and Date<'****'
```

In Java, it would be

```
select * from cases where StartedDate>'1stMONTHDATE' and Date<'TODAYSDATE'
```

My first question is - Within the database, there isn't a field called "Date" as this would have to change on a daily basis. How would I reference this to be the automatically generated date from Java?

Also, how would I implement the Count() method to return an int of the number of records returned?

Comment: Which DB are you using ?

Comment: Apologies. Phpmyadmin (MySQL)

Comment: How do you access your DB? Do you use JDBC, Spring JDBC, JPA, Hibernate...?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM cases WHERE StartedDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

In JPQL:

```
public List<Cases> findAllEvents(Date startDate, Date endDate) {    
  List<Cases> allCases = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM cases WHERE StartedDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")  
  .setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.DATE)  
  .setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.DATE)  
  .getResultList();
        return allCases ;  
    }
```

Comment: BETWEEN is not the same as `>` and `<`. Aaron Bertrand has written a good article about this - [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 0):

Well i suppose by "Date" in the query you mean end date.
if that is so you can calculate the  end date with either of the two following methods

1. java using the Calender class and pass the end date as parameter to the query
2. In the sql by modifying the query like

for ex- here the end date is one month from start date.This is DB specific.This will work in Postgres. Look for the correct syntax according to the DB you use to get the end date

```
select * from cases where StartedDate>'1stMONTHDATE' and ('StartedDate' + INTERVAL '1 MONTH')<'TODAYSDATE'.
```

Regarding the count()-A simple `SELECT Count(*)` will give you the number of rows returned by thw query

Comment: Would you need a result set and the .next() operation to return the count value to display in Java?

Comment: NO.of rows - select COUNT(*) from cases where StartedDate>'1stMONTHDATE' and ('StartedDate' + INTERVAL '1 MONTH')<'TODAYSDATE'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MSSQL` and your date values are as `String` then you can use following query:

```
SELECT c FROM cases c where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),StartDate,121) between :startDate AND :endDate
```

I am using this query in my application with mssql server